# unable to run a Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, buildx, docker-buildkit

i am unable to build a Dockerfile
i am getting an error statiing that
(DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/ubuntu/Dockerfile: no such file or directory)

can any one please guide me on this

i have tried to install buildx (apt buildx install) no luck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If docker is complaining about the legacy builder it means that you haven't created or bootstrapped a custom builder using the `docker buildx create` command. This is a prerequisite step before using buildx to create architecture specific and multi-arch images.

Ex:

```
docker buildx create --driver-opt image=moby/buildkit:latest --name multi-architecture-builder --use
docker buildx inspect --bootstrap
```

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/buildx/create/) is the official docker documentation on the issue.